# Aloe ferox or aloe broomii?

Tags: identification, indoors, succulents, aloe

I have this plant for at least a dozen or so years, I do not remember the source. It survived all ;) Her spines are very hard and sharp, colored at the ends in brown/red. They are on the edges of the leaves and one row also in the middle of the bottom of the leaf. It grows very slowly, recently the lower leaves began to die and the plant began to form a kind of trunk. I do not know if it is normal, whether I should worry about it, I have not changed anything in the way it was treated. Perhaps aloe has reached the age of creating a trunk? By the way, what do you think about it? 
I really care about its correct identification. I think it's either aloe ferox or broomii. Maybe some other species of aloe? Help me please.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: In the picture a matchbox for size comparison.]
[image]